# Your app is not allowed to specify 'AD SERVICES CONFIG' property in the manifest

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

i trying to upload my app in playstore internal testing its giving me error  "Your app is not allowed to specify 'AD SERVICES CONFIG' property in the manifest" i don't why this giving this error is there any solution there to fix this ?
[image]

here is my menifest.xml file
[image]

solution for this error

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I don't know anything about this, but here (https://developer.android.com/design-for-safety/privacy-sandbox/setup-api-access#configure-api-specific) it says that to use this stuff you need to be enrolled - I can't see you declaring this stuff yourself, so are you maybe using a beta version of a library that is? Check your dependencies and maybe move to the latest stable version. Also you might want to delete that screenshot, it contains information you forgot to hide

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `AD_SERVICES_CONFIG` in your manifest, so seems like some of your libraries use it.

1. You can find `AD_SERVICES_CONFIG` in Merged Manifest:

[image]

2. Double-click on `AD_SERVICES_CONFIG` and find what library uses this property.

In my case that was Unity Ads library version `4.7.0`

[image]

3. Update this library to the latest version (if possible)

To fix this issue I updated the Unity Ads library to the latest `4.7.1` version

4. Check if your Merged Manifest still contains `AD_SERVICES_CONFIG`. If not, then you fixed this issue